# asp.net dropdown navigation menu controller change issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, layout

So I created dropdown menu in _Layout.cshtml.

```
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
                       role="button" aria-expanded="false"><span>Menu</span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("FirstAction", "Action", "Controller1")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Second", "second", "Controller2", new { wszystko = true })</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Third", "Third", "Controller3")</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

On every run I can only once choose position from the menu. When I try to pick different action, application didn't see I want to change Controller. When I want to change action, application always searches in controller I'm currently in.

For example: if I am in *Controller1/Action* and I want to go to *Controller2/Second*, program always search for *Controller1/Second* action result.

Before I created that menu, links work fine. Can somebody tell me why is it happening?

Comment: Maybe if you use `@Url.Content` instead of `@Html.ActionLink`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only overload for `ActionLink` that takes four parameters is:

`HtmlHelper.ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)`

Note there is no controller name.  You need to use

`HtmlHelper.ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)`

For example

`@Html.ActionLink("Second", "second", "Controller2", new { wszystko = true }, null`)

Comment: Thanks, that was it :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using  `Html.ActionLink` method overload incorrectly.

Use [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Object%29) overload. The fifth parameter is to specify any html attributes for the element (Ex : css class name etc). If you do not have any, just pass `null`

```
@Html.ActionLink("Second", "second", "Controller2", new { wszystko = true },null)
```